# What does the Docker for Mac status "Running" mean?

Tags: macos, docker

When I double click on the Docker for Mac icon in the menu bar, I see an icon appearing:

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1) How can I get the same effect through the command line ? 
-> as of today, the command line just gives me the docker commands

```
Mac:bin romain$ docker
Usage: docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND [arg...]
       docker [ --help | -v | --version ]

A self-sufficient runtime for containers.

Options:

  --config=~/.docker              Location of client config files
  -D, --debug                     Enable debug mode
  -H, --host=[]                   Daemon socket(s) to connect to
  -h, --help                      Print usage
  -l, --log-level=info            Set the logging level
  --tls                           Use TLS; implied by --tlsverify
  --tlscacert=~/.docker/ca.pem    Trust certs signed only by this CA
  --tlscert=~/.docker/cert.pem    Path to TLS certificate file
  --tlskey=~/.docker/key.pem      Path to TLS key file
  --tlsverify                     Use TLS and verify the remote
  -v, --version                   Print version information and quit

Commands:
    attach    Attach to a running container
    build     Build an image from a Dockerfile
    commit    Create a new image from a container's changes
    cp        Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
    create    Create a new container
    diff      Inspect changes on a container's filesystem
    events    Get real time events from the server
    exec      Run a command in a running container
```

2) What do they mean by  "docker is running" - I understand containers can be up, but Docker?

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/1105087/starting-docker-for-mac-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `open -a Docker` on the command line.

For Docker "to be running" means that the Docker daemon is able to accept commands, like `docker ps`, and do what you expect, like pass your command to the appropriate container, or return something from the container or daemon.

Answer (score 1):

When Docker for Mac says that it is running, it means that the virtualized Docker environment is running on your machine. Docker for Mac uses [xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve/) to run a small Linux VM on your Mac.

Docker itself runs as a daemon inside of that VM. The status in the Docker for Mac menu bar icon shows whether that Linux VM has been started or not.

The `docker` command you can run in the Terminal allows you to interact with the Docker daemon that is running in that Linux VM. You can use the `docker` command to build images or to create/start/stop containers.